# Create a drop down list from a shell script output in php

Tags: php

I have a shell script it produce list of project and directed to a text file.In php i want this project list in a drop down box and if selected any one project in that list it will directed to other php page.Please help me in this scenario.

My code here

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can use `fopen` to open text file and then iterate its values to populate dropdown

Comment: Please post your code it will be useful to know what's wrong with you

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would help:

```
echo "<select name='dummydd'>";
$handle = fopen("file.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        echo "<option value='".$line."'>".$line."</option>";
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: Thank you so much.Here i am able to display the drop down list but not able to select a content and submit from that list.I want to select a content from that list and when i click submit button it will redirect to other page.Can you help on this.